# r: select row with highest year followed by highest month

Tags: r, dplyr

For my data frame I want to filter the row with the highest year followed by the highest month.

Sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5),
                 year = c(2018,2018,2018,2018,2019),
                 month = c(9,10,11,12,11))
```

I tried the following but this does not return any record (which makes sense, because the max year and max month are in different rows). Does anybody have the answer? Obviously my desired output would be row 5.

```
df %>% filter(year == max(year) & month == max(month))
```

Comment: Try chaining together your filter statements: `df %>% filter(year == max(year)) %>% filter(month == max(month))`

Comment: Thanks! I've been staring at my code for so long, I don't even see the obvious anymore ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We can do:

```
df %>% 
   filter(year==max(year) & lag(month) == max(month))
  ID year month
1  5 2019    11
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give back the highest year containing the highest month value within that year.

```
df <- df %>%
  arrange(desc(year), desc(month))

  ID year month
1  5 2019    11
2  4 2018    12
3  3 2018    11
4  2 2018    10
5  1 2018     9


df[1,] #  first row

  ID year month
1  5 2019    11
```